# Validating Form using codeigniter

Tags: validation, codeigniter-2

I have the following form:

```
<label>One</label> 
 Product ID:<input type="text" name="productid[]" value=""> 
 Product Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value=""> <br>

<label>Two</label> 
 Product ID:<input type="text" name="productid[]" value=""> 
 Product Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value=""> <br>

<label>Three</label> 
 Product ID:<input type="text" name="productid[]" value=""> 
 Product Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value=""> <br>

 <!-- there may be more inputs like above (users can create new inputs 
    as many as they want) // I have a jquery function to create new rows-->


  <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Now My question is how to validate the form using Codeigniter when I have input names like this- `name="productid[]"` instead of `name="productid"` in my form.

Usually I use to validate my form like this [way](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) but this time it won't work for the form above.

How to validate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the literal field names, with brackets:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('product_id[]', 'Product', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity[]', 'Quantity', 'required');
```

This will run the validation on *every* field with that name. If you have to validate only a specific index, once again - use the literal field name (and specify the index in your HTML):

```
// <input name="product_id[3]">
$this->form_validation->set_rules('product_id[3]', 'Product', 'required');
```

It's all in the [documentation for Codeigniter's Form Validation class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields):

> ## Using Arrays as Field Names
>
> The Form Validation class supports the use of arrays as field
>   names.  Consider this example:
>
> `<input type="text" name="options[]" value="" size="50"
>   />`
>
> If you do use an array as a field name, you must use the EXACT
>   array name in the Helper Functions that
>   require the field name, and as your Validation Rule field name.
>
> For example, to set a rule for the above field you would use:
>
> `$this->form_validation->set_rules('options[]', 'Options',
>   'required');`
>
> Or, to show an error for the above field you would use:
>
> `<?php echo form_error('options[]'); ?>`
>
> Or to re-populate the field you would use:
>
> `<input type="text" name="options[]" value="<?php echo
>   set_value('options[]'); ?>" size="50" />`
>
> You can use multidimensional arrays as field names as well. For
>   example:
>
> `<input type="text" name="options[size]" value="" size="50"
>   />`
>
> Or even:
>
> `<input type="text" name="sports[nba][basketball]" value=""
>   size="50" />`
>
> As with our first example, you must use the exact array name in the
>   helper functions:
>
> `<?php echo form_error('sports[nba][basketball]'); ?>`
>
> If you are using checkboxes (or other fields) that have multiple
>   options, don't forget to leave an empty bracket after each option, so
>   that all selections will be added to the POST array:
>
> `<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="red" />
>
>   <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="blue" />
>
>   <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="green" />`
>
> Or if you use a multidimensional array:
>
> `<input type="checkbox" name="options[color][]" value="red"
>   />
>  <input type="checkbox" name="options[color][]"
>   value="blue" />
>  <input type="checkbox"
>   name="options[color][]" value="green" />`
>
> When you use a helper function you'll include the bracket as
>   well:
>
> `<?php echo form_error('options[color][]'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Did You try [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields) ...? A few lines below in the guide ...